# Decreasing the address of the stack pointer

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this structure of code in MIPS:

```
.data

.text
li a0, 5

fun:
   addi sp, sp, -20
   sw ra, 4(sp)
   sw a0, 12(sp)
   li t0, 7
   beq a0, t0, done
   addi a0, a0, 1
   jal fun
   lw a0, 12(sp)
   add t0, a0, a0
done:
   lw ra, 4(sp)
   addi sp, sp, 20
   jr ra
```

The sp address begins at 0x7FFFF628
Problem is that the address that I write (0x7FFFF608) when I allocated space for my stack it's not correct and it is 0x7FFFF600. Can you explain me why?

I tried to go with algorithm but it gives me 0x7FFFF608

Comment: This is pretty simple math, just try to make sure you're working with all the numbers in the same number base, as you know what you're showing is mixing decimal and hex.

Comment: That code is allocating 5 words of stack space, but using only 2 of them (of course, we're presuming a 32-bit machine).  I would have tightened up the stack allocation and done `addi sp, sp, -8; sw ra,0(sp); sw a0,4(sp) ...,`.

Comment: If you're trying to follow the standard calling convention, the function return value goes in `v0`, not `t0`, so `add t0, a0, a0` should be `add v0, a0, a0`.

Comment: For a function returning integer, we need to return a value on every possible path through the function.  The base case, where the argument == 7 doesn't set the function return value register.

Comment: That code is not properly calling the function.  It should be called from a (test) main via `jal` which sets up the return address register, otherwise there's no address of where for it to return to.  A (test) main should also expect the function to return to it, and so needs proper termination (e.g. via syscall #10 for MARS/QtSpim).